# "set" statement RMySQL and DBI package

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql, r-dbi

I am using 'RMySQL' and 'DBI' for MySQL database connection. 
Does anyone know if it is possible to use the

```
set @variable := something
```

when sending queries with `DBI::dbGetQuery` function?

When trying to pass the query, I am getting an error that my syntax doesn't match MySQL version. 
Isn't it that I am just passing a text to my MySQL database and, thus, using "set" is fine? Not getting it. May be it has something to do with encodings of R string that I am sending and MySQL encodings